# Timestamp data type in sql developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

In SQL Developer, I have field which type is `timestamp(6)`

When I am trying insert in this field data like this: `2013-07-10 12:22:22`, SQL Developer shows error: `not a valid month`.

I have this settings in sql developer:
[image]

Can you tell me please why happened this error?

Comment: SQL Server is not oracle. And vice versa

Comment: Try this:- **select sysdate from dual;** to check the present system setting of date and then insert accordingly

Comment: @Mat --- And how to change format string parameter as `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` for `to_timestamp()` function as default ? @Rahul `select sysdate from dual` returns: `2013-10-13`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT has an error; you have the `MM` element twice. It should be:

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS
```

If you only use `HH` for the hour element you won't be able to distinguish between morning and afternoon times; `HH24` will give you `01` for 1 AM and `13` for 1 PM, for example. The minute element is `MI`, not `MM`. At the moment it's trying to interpret `22` as a month number, which is invalid, as the error says.

But why use a `timestamp` over a `date` if you don't want the fractional seconds?

You should not rely on NLS settings anyway, generally. It would be much better, in anything other than ad hoc queries, to use `to_timestamp('2013-07-10 12:22:22', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')` to avoid any ambiguity and surprises when someone else runs your code with different NLS settings.